# How to position bullets and tooltips in the center of an stepped line chart using amCharts v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, amcharts4

This is my current chart, I am using amCharts v4.

[image]

I want to be able to position both bullets and tooltips in the center of each step line, like the red dots I added to the image.

This are the options that I use to generate the code:

```
    const x = am4core.create('chartdiv', am4charts.XYChart);
    const dateAxis = x.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    dateAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    dateAxis.baseInterval = {
      timeUnit: 'minute',
      count: 1,
    };

    const valueAxis = x.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.title.text = mode === 'consumptions' ? 'Demanda (kW)' : 'Energía (kWh)';
    valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

    const series = x.series.push(
      mode === 'consumptions' ? new am4charts.LineSeries() : new am4charts.StepLineSeries()
    );
    series.dataFields.dateX = 'date';
    series.dataFields.valueY = 'value';
    series.tooltipText =
      mode === 'consumptions'
        ? 'Demanda: {valueY.value} kW \n Fecha: {dateX.formatDate("dd/MM/YYYY")} \n Hora: {dateX.formatDate("HH:mm")}'
        : 'Energía: {valueY.value} kWh \n Fecha: {dateX.formatDate("dd/MM/YYYY")} \n Hora: {dateX.formatDate("HH:mm")}';
    x.dateFormatter.dateFormat = 'dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm';
    series.dataItems.template.locations.dateX = 0;
  
    if (mode === 'energy') {
      const bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
      bullet.fill = am4core.color('white');
      bullet.strokeWidth = 3;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!